# The Unknown clan

Tags: naruto

One of the most interesting clans in my opinion is Juugos clan, the clan with the ability to enter sage mode but with a downside of uncontrolled "Beserk sessions".
Lord Orochimaru experimented on Juugo and later on, found that the source of Juugo's clans power was from the Ryuuchi cave;
[image]

Does this mean Juugo's clan originated at the Ryuuchi cave?
 Also, is Juugo the last surviving member of his clan?

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the power originated from there. That is not enough to say that they themselves originated from the Ryūchi Cave.

We don't know. The only known member is Jūgo, who was said to have voluntarily gone to Orochimaru. It is possible that the clan still exists and has members. It's unknown.